# feednix install in ubuntu but some problem

Tags: 14.04, command-line

hey i went to install feednix in my ubuntu but some error is come.
(if more information need plz comment below )

```
najeeb@najeeb:~/Documents/Feednix$ feednix 
  cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/xdg/feednix/config.json’: No such file or directory
  chmod: cannot access ‘/home/najeeb/.config/feednix/config.json’: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue raised in GitHub [issue#38](https://github.com/Jarkore/Feednix/issues/38) which states that the config.json file is not created automatically during install, you need to copy it from the repository.

My suggestion is to create the directory first by doing this in the terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/feednix/
```

Then type in the following to create the default settings:

```
cat > ~/.config/feednix/config.json << EOF
{
    "colors" : { 

        /* ====== Color Definitions =======
         *  BLACK   0
         *  RED     1
         *  GREEN   2
         *  YELLOW  3
         *  BLUE    4
         *  MAGENTA 5
         *  CYAN    6
         *  WHITE   7
         * ================================ */

        "background" : 0,
        "active_panel" : 1,
        "idle_panel" : 6,
        "counter" : 5,
        "status_line" : 7,
        "instructions_line" : 4,
        "item_text" : 7,
        "item_highlight" : 2,
        "read_item" : 3
    },
    "ctg_win_width" : 40,
    //"view_win_height" : 200,
    "view_win_height_per" : 50,
    // Count of posts to be retrived per request. Maximum is 10000
    "posts_retrive_count" : "500",
    //Feedly API Allows for two sort types:
        // Newest(default) false 
        // Oldest true 
    "rank" : false,
    "preview_active" : true 
}
EOF
```

Then try running feednix again:

```
feednix
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: You might need to store the json file in your `/etc` folder too. Do this by first running `sudo mkdir -p /etc/xdg/feednix` to make sure the directory exists, then run `sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jarkore/Feednix/master/config.json -O /etc/xdg/feednix/config.json` to download and install the `config.json` from the repo.